# Column not in index Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called opp_sacc.

```
opp_sacc.columns.tolist()
```

I get :

```
['intgid$_x',
 'ps$_x',
 'id$_x',
 'batch_start$_x',
 'batch_end$_x',
 'value_start$',
 'value_end$',
 'name',
 'amount_currency',
 'currency_code_x',
 'currency_code_l$_x',
 'amount_eur',
 'creation_date_x',
 'last_update_date',
 'record_type_l$',
 'opp_type',
 'opp_business_type',
 'opp_category',
 'opp_scope_attribut',
 'opp_priority_level',
 'opp_source',
 'stage',
 'gate',
 'probability_pct',
 'status',
  ]
```

I try to extract a susbset dataframe composed only from these columns : 'intgid$_x', 'ps$_x', 
I try with :

```
opp_sacc=opp_sacc[['intgid$_x','id$_x']]
```

But I got this error :

```
KeyError: "['intgid$_x' 'id$_x'] not in index"
```

Could you help me please to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: It work find on my side

Answer (score 0):

If your exact error message is

```
KeyError: "['intgid$_x' 'id$_x'] not in index"
```

it seems you are missing the comma. Did you tried exactly

```
opp_sacc=opp_sacc[['intgid$_x','id$_x']]
```

as you wrote?

Comment: Yes I wrote `opp_sacc=opp_sacc[['intgid$_x','id$_x']]`